# Is linker's addend field for non-32 bit?

Tags: linker, ld

When inspecting an object file e.g. one of those in `/usr/lib32` or `/usr/lib` with `readelf -r <object file>`, it seems that the 32-bit variants do not have an addend field, while the 64-bit ones do have. I guess that it is to fix the address layout for non-32 bit system e.g. x86_64 or arm. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distinction between RELA (explicit addend) vs. REL (addend stored at modified offset) relocations is mostly historic. It all started with REL to save space but most modern architectures use RELA to [speed up linking](https://www.technovelty.org/linux/rel-v-rela-relocations.html). Theoretically static/dynamic linkers should support both REL and RELA or any mix thereof (see e.g. discussion [here](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2013-November/067198.html)).